# Hazelcast aggregator : how to implement aggregator for group by

Tags: hazelcast

[This](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/distributed-map/aggregations/src/main/java/AggregationsDemo.java) sample code gives an example on getting sum of salary for a given company

```
int avgSalary = employees.aggregate(
                Supplier.fromPredicate(
                        (entry) -> "Hazelcast".equals(mapEntry.getValue().getCompanyName(),
                                Supplier.all((value) -> value.getSalaryPerMonth())
                        ), Aggregations.integerAvg());
```

Is it possible to get the aggregation based on set of attributes? 
i.e. instead of applying a filter on company, can I group by company? If not aggregators, does SQL predicate support this?

---

EDIT:
I was able to write a custom aggregator

```
class DayLocalSumGroupByBookAggregator extends Aggregator<Map.Entry<Long, Pnl>, Map<Integer, Double>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Map<Integer, Double> bookToSumOfDayLocal ;

        @Override
        public void accumulate(Entry<Long, Pnl> input) {
            Integer bookId = input.getValue().getBookId();
            if(bookToSumOfDayLocal == null ){
                bookToSumOfDayLocal = new HashMap<>();
            }
            Double sum = bookToSumOfDayLocal.get(bookId);
            if(sum == null){
                sum = 0d;
            }
            sum += input.getValue().getDayLocal();
            bookToSumOfDayLocal.put(bookId, sum);
        }

        @Override
        public void combine(Aggregator aggregator) {
            //TODO
        }

        @Override
        public Map<Integer, Double> aggregate() {
            return bookToSumOfDayLocal;
        }

    }
```

but it does get complicated when I need multiple aggregations (sum for more than one attributes) and group by multiple fields. Will this be supported in further versions?

Comment: Please see the fast-aggregations examples since this is the successor api :)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the fast-aggregations. but still, is there any support for map.aggregate to return result which is a map of fields (grouped by) and the aggregated result (like sum of the salary)

Comment: Requirement is more like, there is a huge amount of data object in cache. depending on the user requirement, we group the data at certain levels and send the data back to the users. Example : in accounting world, there are profit and loss computed across various levels (granular level or at top level). It is more like the user click on the level he wants to see that data with some basic filter (like show me only the last month accounting details) and the records are given back with certain properties of the object aggregated at the mentioned level

Answer (score 0):

Group by will be supported in further version. For now you need to stick to custom implementation. It's not that tough to accumulate sums for multiple attributes grouped by a property. Just have a map of values, etc.